# PyQt simple cookies/session

Tags: python, pyqt

For my current project I need to create a stand alone PyQt interface with user authentication. Should I use HTTP_COOKIE similar to web app in this case? Are there different approaches I can use with PyQt for simple user login session/cookie?

The SimpleCookie doesn't seem to send anything to os.environ["HTTP_COOKIE"] when testing out the script on IDE